# jQuery map select="multiple" into array

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following element:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="EmployeeId">
    <option selected="selected" value="123">123</option>                                               
    <option value="323">323</option>                                               
    <option value="443">443</option>                                               
    <option value="534">534</option>                                               
    <option value="144">144</option>                                               
    <option value="587">587</option>                                               
    <option value="433">433</option>                                               
</select>
```

I want to get all values (not selected and selected) into an array of integers using `jQuery`. I guess that can be done using `.map`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function combined with `get()`:

```js
console.log($('select.form-control').find('option').map(function() {
  return $(this).val()
}).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="EmployeeId">
    <option selected="selected" value="123">123</option>                                               
    <option value="323">323</option>                                               
    <option value="443">443</option>                                               
    <option value="534">534</option>                                               
    <option value="144">144</option>                                               
    <option value="587">587</option>                                               
    <option value="433">433</option>                                               
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, when I see the ouput data to my ajax I have this: ShortCodes:32997,32997,79496,79496,79496,79496,79496,782929, instead of ShortCodes: [32997,32997,79496,79496,79496,79496,79496,782929] because in my server method I need to receive a List

Comment: Im doing this:
// get short codes list
            var employeeIds= $('#emp-id').find('option').map(function () {
                return $(this).val()
            }).get()

            data.push({ name: 'EmployeeIds', value: employeeIds});

Comment: The value is a list. I'm not sure if you need a list or a string (that looks like list - numbers separated with commas).

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the array of options and then you can apply map over that. But you can do this with each as well.

```
$('#EmployeeId').find('option').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: As map is applied over array and rind('option') returns array you can easily replace each with map

Answer (score 0):

you can just get all the values using $('select').text() and assign it to array

check this snippet

```js
var foo = $('#empselect').text();
console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="empselect" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="EmployeeId">
  <option selected="selected" value="123">123</option>
  <option value="323">323</option>
  <option value="443">443</option>
  <option value="534">534</option>
  <option value="144">144</option>
  <option value="587">587</option>
  <option value="433">433</option>
</select>
```

Hope it helps